# What is an Infinite Word™?

Tags: word-property

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) and [What is a Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) and their spin-off [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.*

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it an Infinite Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{1.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Infinite }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\ \def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2018.03.05}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{OMISSION}&\text{HYPOCRISY}\\ \hline
\text{JEALOUSY}&\text{OBLIVIOUS}\\ \hline
\text{OFFSTAGE}&\text{ISOLATION}\\ \hline
\text{YAWNER}&\text{EXCITER}\\ \hline
\text{SOCIETAL}&\text{MISANTHROPE}\\ \hline
\text{FRENZIED}&\text{HOEDOWN}\\ \hline
\text{YACHTSWOMEN}&\text{KLEPTOMANIACS}\\ \hline
\text{VACUOUS}&\text{PHILOSOPHIC}\\ \hline
\text{UNSOCIAL}&\text{SEGREGATION}\\ \hline
\text{IMMOLATE}&\text{ZEPPELIN}\\ \hline
\text{HEATEDLY}&\text{HEAT}\\ \hline
\text{QUESTION}&\text{WEASEL}\\ \hline
\text{SEPULCHER}&\text{JAIL}\\ \hline
\text{ESCAPISM}&\text{WONDER}\\ \hline
\text{MUTATION}&\text{UNIQUE}\\ \hline
\text{TRICKERY}&\text{OPINION}\\ \hline
\text{VERIFIED}&\text{VALIDATION}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

---

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Infinite Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Infinite Words™, many more exist.

CSV version for Analysis:

OMISSION,HYPOCRISY
JEALOUSY,OBLIVIOUS
OFFSTAGE,ISOLATION
YAWNER,EXCITER
SOCIETAL,MISANTHROPE
FRENZIED,HOEDOWN
YACHTSWOMEN,KLEPTOMANIACS
VACUOUS,PHILOSOPHIC
UNSOCIAL,SEGREGATION
IMMOLATE,ZEPPELIN
HEATEDLY,HEAT
QUESTION,WEASEL
SEPULCHER,JAIL
ESCAPISM,WONDER
MUTATION,UNIQUE
TRICKERY,OPINION
VERIFIED,VALIDATION

Comment: It doesn't particularly matter (I assume), but you have two ISOLATIONs in the right-hand column.

Comment: Oh, and two MISANTHROPEs.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan TY, changed them to UNIQUE ones. :)

Comment: And two WONDERs.

Comment: I knew I should've put them through the deduper...

Comment: As testament to OP's good sense of including many, many samples, I'd like to point out that the first six pairs also conform to the rule "even number of letters in infinite words only".

Comment: An infinite word is one that goes on without end.  Consider, for example, the infinite word "banananananananananananananananananananananananan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An Infinite Word™...

> has a single capital letter with a closed region (e.g. A, D, O, P, Q, or R) in its left half and one in its right half, with the center letter of odd-lettered words not being one of those. This bears similarity to an infinity symbol, where there is a closed region on each side (hence the name Infinite Word™, I presume).
>
>  There is one undefined condition: it's unclear from the examples above how to consider the letter B, since it has *two* closed regions. The only word with a B is OBLIVIOUS, which is already disqualified as an Infinite Word™ because it has an O on the right and a OB on the left. If a letter B is treated just like any other letter with a closed region then, for example, BIGOT would be an Infinite Word™.

Comment: Does "OBLIVIOUS" fail because of the "B" then?

Comment: @AlexisOlson: Yeah.

Comment: Yes. rot13 (Bqq yrggrerq jbeqf pnaabg unir n "ubyr" va gur zvqqyr yrggre, naq "O" artngrf *nal* jbeq.)

Comment: Is it wrong for me to have considered calling this type "A Tainted Word™?"

Comment: Shouldn't "Q" negate a word in the same way "B" does? The font in the table displays a "Q" with two holes. Or will we just ignore this fact? @Chowzen

Comment: @Riley: I'd presume we would ignore that, and just consider the standard fixed-width font.

Comment: @Riley I was going by [this table](http://www.rinkworks.com/words/lettergroups.shtml). I'm not sure that one could cite any source on the subject as "indisputable," but I'd generally consider a Q as having one hole.

Comment: The "undefined condition" noted in the answer, to me at least, is clear. Any B in any position makes two holes—either on the left, the right, or (god forbid!) in the middle—disqualifying the word.

Answer (score 9):

Infinite words:

> have exactly two holes in their all-caps form, like $\infty$ does. Non-infinite words have $0,1$ or $\gt2$ holes.

Comment: except for ZEPPELIN

Comment: soooooo close...

Comment: NIPPLE = Infinite word... but NIPPLES is *not* Infinite

Comment: @Chowzen Does that mean SUPPLE is infinite but AMPLE is not?  =D  Specifically because 'gurl erdhver bar ubyr ba rvgure fvqr bs gur jbeq'?

Comment: @hagfy This is true.